# Remove a View using Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a View like so:

```
(function(views) {
    views.FilterView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        events: {
            'click a.remove': 'remove'
        },
        template: _.template($("#filterViewTemplate").html()),

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            return this;
        },
        remove: function (e) {
            this.remove();
            this.unbind();
        }
    });
})(app.views);
```

It's template is:

```
<script type="text/html" id="filterViewTemplate">
    <select class="filterByOption">
        <option value="Account">Account</option>
        <option value="Owner">Owner</option>
    </select>

    <span class="cell sort">
        <input class="filterString cell" type="text" />
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="btn small remove">Remove</a>
</script>
```

But when I click on `Remove` I get the following error:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in your `remove` method your calling `this.remove()` which calls `remove()` which calls `remove()` which calls `remove()`...

Comment: You could try `this.constructor.__super__.remove.call(this)` instead.

Comment: A cosmetic tip, but I like to name the function that removes the view and events `cleanup`. Just my 2 cents